# How can we change what is currently __main__

Tags: python, python-3.x, program-entry-point, contextmanager

Suppose we execute `script_1`. So, `script_1` is `__main__`. However, `script_1` imports some classes from `script_2`. Is there some way, when we enter `script_2` to save the old `__main__` context, make `script_2` the new `__main__`, and before going back into `script_1`, restore the old context?

Comment: Importing doesn't change what is `__main__`. On the script that is executed is `__main__`.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I smell an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Ask what you really want to know, not what you think you need to know.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? There is no practical use case for this scenario. You probably need to rewrite some things in `script_2` if you require this.

Comment: There is a practical use case for this problem. When two servers want to communicate without replicating the codes.

Answer (score 4):

**Important note:** i agree with the comments. It is very suspicious that you need to do that

For the sport, here is a way to do waht you ask using `importlib`:

script_2.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('script_2 is the main!')
```

script_1.py:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('__main__', 'script_2.py')
mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('script_3 is the main!')
```

Finally

```
python script_1.py
> script_2 is the main!
> script_1 is the main!
```

Comment: I just want to point out that this won't add `script_2` to `sys.modules`. If you do `import script_2` anywhere in the code, you'll have two different copies of the `script_2` module - one of them with the name `__main__` and one with the name `script_2`.

Comment: In script_1.py, did you mean to use `print('script_1 is the main!')` ?